# Extension Methods in T4

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, t4, tangible-t4-editor

I'm trying to use [PGK.Extensions](http://dnpextensions.codeplex.com/) in a T4 template in VS2008 for VB.NET and I get:

> RemoveAllSpecialCharacters is not a member of string..

My T4 headers:

```
<#@ template language="VB" hostspecific="false" debug="true" inherits="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.VSHost.ModelingTextTransformation" #>
<#@ output extension="vb" #>

<#@ assembly name="PGK.Extensions.dll" #> // the dll is found
<#@ import namespace="StringExtensions" #> //Try with and without namespace
```

Use of extension in block code:

```
<#
   Me.WriteLine(item.Name.RemoveAllSpecialCharacters.ToUpper)
#>
```

RemoveAllSpecialCharacters is a string extension method from PGK.Extensions.dll.

Can anybody help me?

EDITED:

OK. It's:

```
<#@ template language="VBv3.5" ...
```

But this breaks DevArt T4 Editor intellisense and syntax highlight in VS2008 plugin. Use Tangible T4 Editor instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While an extension method appears from code to be applied on an object, it is in fact compiled as a static method. This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bb384936.aspx) from Microsoft will give you more info on that.

So calling item.Name.RemoveAllSpecialCharacters() is in fact compiled as *StringExtensions*.RemoveAllSpecialCharacters(item.Name)

Therefore, you could try writing (not tested, but should work) :

```
<#
    StringExtensions.RemoveAllSpecialCharacters(item.Name).ToUpper()
#>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Its works but this breaks the power of extension methods. I found this link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/garethj/archive/2008/10/30/using-extension-methods-in-t4-templates.aspx and for the author works. Maybe C# but not VB?

Comment: You can always ask MS to properly implement extension methods in T4 templates :D ... But I'm afraid until then you have no other choice.

Comment: And if you specify the version of VB.NET in your declaration ? Something like <#@ template language="VBv9" debug="true" #>, replacing v3.5 with the most recent version number of VB (9 or 10 I believe) ? Does it work ?

Comment: For 2008 is v9. Tried VBv9 and VBv9.0 and it does't work. :( Anyway, I'll mark your answer as accepted. Thanks.

Comment: Another option, if you really want to use extension methods that way, is to write your T4 template in C#, but still have it output VB.Net code, if you don't have any restrictions on the language.

Answer (score 2):

Had a hard time getting this to work myself, even with the blog post found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/garethj/archive/2008/10/30/using-extension-methods-in-t4-templates.aspx) (also referenced by @jlvaquero in a comment above).

what finally worked for me was using the [visual studio macro vars](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs.aspx) then import the namespace

```
 <#@ assembly name="$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)\AssemblyName.dll" #>
```